# dbscan clustering in java for a text file

Tags: java, apache, text-files, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I am going to cluster my data in Java which is in a text file and I want to use the DBSCAN clustering by Apache clusterer, Unfortunately I can't understand hoe it works.
I would be grateful to help me, as I should have done it today :(

Comment: There is a nice wikipedia article on it. Your question is too vague to be answered.